# use rename command on first 5 characters of a file

Tags: linux, rename, bulk

using linux's rename utility
I have files that are named similar to

```
kbb.12.06.14.actual_name.jpg
kbb.13.05.13.actual_name.jpg
kbb.11.11.29.actual_name.jpg
```

and I want to change that to

```
actual_name.kbb.12.06.14.jpg
actual_name.kbb.13.05.13.jpg
actual_name.kbb.11.11.29.jpg
```

I know I can get the beginning of a file with

```
rename 's/^/something/' *
```

but is there a way to select from the beginning to a certain length in the file? Similar to an array.

Comment: The `rename` utility on my (CentOS 7) system doesn't seem to support regular expressions like `'s/^/something/`. Are you sure it does on yours? If so, which distribution/version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perl regex syntax for selecting the first 13 characters would be this:

```
s/^.{13}/something/'
```

Similarly, if you wanted to match the *last* 13 characters you could use this:

```
s/.{13}$/something/'
```

The `^` is an *anchor* to the beginning of the string and `$` is an anchor for the end of the string.

Comment: Great! Do you know how to use this to move those first 13 characters to the end of a file?

Comment: @user3795137 I've updated my answer to include the syntax for both beginning and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex group matching.

```
rename 's/(.*)(actual_name\.)/$2$1/' *
```